# Applicationhost.config - cannot write configuration due to insufficient permission

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7

I am deploying a c# webservice application to a machine with: Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, framework 4 but i am encountering this error while converting it to application

"There was an error while performing this operation
Details:
Filename:
\?c:\WIndows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file due to insufficient permission
"

I already deployed several webservice application on the same machine without this error before. I already added iis to have permission on the application i am deploying.
Can you guide me what went wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I have seen this error occur when there is 0 bytes with hard drive c:\ where applications are installed. Freeing some space resolves the problem. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the IIS had a "Shared Configuration" set on a clustered IIS.

Before you do the solution get the password and encryption key for the shared config.

To solve the problem I unchecked "Enable shared configuration" made my changes and checked it again, adding username, password and encryption key.

Regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

In the .cproj file of my project that was experiencing an error, the project's name was changed to the name of the application configured in IIS.

My application was pointing to the IIS URL "application360", however, in IIS, the application's name is "application360Services". By correcting this name in the .cproj file, the application started working correctly again.

From:

```
<WebProjectProperties>
...
<IISUrl>http://localhost/application360</IISUrl>
...
</WebProjectProperties>
```

To:

```
<WebProjectProperties>
...
<IISUrl>http://localhost/application360Services</IISUrl>
...
</WebProjectProperties>
```